# Problema al enlazar click en botón de ToolBar con un método

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Estoy realizando una aplicación grande donde intento llamar una definición desde otra a través del gestor de evento `Bin` específicamente en esta parte:

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, agEv)`

pero no funciona, no llama a la función y no se porqué ni que estoy haciendo mal... A continuación les dejo la clase completa:

```
class ListCtrlRight(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_HRULES | 
        wx.LC_NO_HEADER | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        self.Hide()
        self.parent = parent

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

        self.InsertColumn(0, '')

        self.panel=wx.Panel(self.parent, size=(700,800))

    def Evento(self, event):

        self.index = 0
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, pos=((50,70)), size=(610,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN|wx.CENTRE
                         )

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Nombre', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Apellido', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Direccion', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, 'Sexo', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(4, 'Cedula', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(5, 'Accion', width=100)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM persona")
        resultados = cursor.fetchall() #muestra la fila
        for row in resultados:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, row[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, row[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 3, row[5])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 4, str(row[7]))
            self.list_ctrl.Select(self.index)
            self.index += 1


        toolbar = wx.ToolBar( self.panel, -1)
        toolbar.SetBackgroundColour("#FF0")
        self.st_to= wx.StaticText(toolbar, -1, 'Evento Sede la Cascada', (35, 7))
        self.st_to.SetForegroundColour("#1355EA")
        toolbar.AddStretchableSpace()
        agEv= toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'AgrEv', wx.Bitmap('img/add_user2.png'))
        toolbar.Realize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, agEv) # Aqui intento llamar la funcion onclick

    def OnClick(self):
        AggEvt(None)


    def OnSize(self, event):
        size = self.parent.GetSize()
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, size.x-5)
        event.Skip()
```

Comment: ¿Le genera algún error este código? Si es así, por favor [edit] la pregunta con los detalles del error (o errores) obtenido(s).

Comment: No me genera error pero tampoco realiza la accion...

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente buscas ejecutar `OnClick` cuando se hace click en `agEv`. el problema es que estas intentando capturar un evento que no es generado por `ToolBar` (`EVT_BUTTON`).

Los botones de herramientas genéricos  emiten el evento [`EVT_TOOL`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ToolBar.html#events-events-emitted-by-this-class):

```
import wx 


class Demo(wx.Frame): 

    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Demo, self).__init__(parent, title = title)  
        toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self, -1)
        agEv = toolbar.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'AgrEv', wx.Bitmap('img/add_user2.png'))
        toolbar.Realize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnClick, agEv)
        self.SetSize(0,0,400, 100)
        self.Show(True)


    def OnClick(self, event):
        print("Click")



ex = wx.App() 
Demo(None,'ToolBar demo') 
ex.MainLoop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota**: El método `AddLabelTool` está marcado actualmente como "deprecated" en favor de `AddTood`, al igual que `InsertStringItem` (por `InsertItem`) y `SetStringItem` (por `SetItem`). Dependiendo de que versión uses de wxPython deberías tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: el ´EVT_TOOL´ no me soluciona el error, aun persiste ... no puedo llamar a una definición a través del Bind, No me da Error pero tampoco hace lo que se quiere que es llamar a la funcion.. Gracias por responder

Comment: ¿@FaustinoVelasquez el ejemplo que muestro tal y como está te funciona (te imprime "Click")? Tenia un error tipográfico, faltaba una comilla de apertura en la ruta del archivo a la imágen. Acabo de probarlo y no hay problema alguno, la función es llamada sin problemas cuando se hace click en el Tool como cabe esperar... He añadido una captura mostrandolo. Un saludo.

Comment: muchisimas gracias FJSevilla... lo he solucionado... Gracias por tu aporte... Saludos

Comment: @FaustinoVelasquez si esta respuesta te ayudó, considera [darle un voto positivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) o, si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, marca la respuesta como [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), o incluso, si deseas compartir la solución, puedes [responder a tu propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.